# Scaling UI exactly as Gameobject

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a gameobject in my scene. I want to show the dimension of the gameobject as shown here: [image] So, I created a UI prefab. Now when I am trying to scale the UI (Which us a world UI canvas) prefab. It's not scaling properly! How can I do it? I am trying this now which is indeed not working. Help Needed!

```
public void setDimension()
{
    GameObject g = Instantiate(dimUiPrefab);
    BoxCollider b = activeFurniture.GetComponent<BoxCollider>();
    Vector2 cameraViewPort = 
    Camera.main.WorldToViewportPoint(activeFurniture.transform.lossyScale);



    g.transform.position = new Vector3(b.transform.position.x/2,b.transform.position.y +2f, b.transform.position.z);
    g.GetComponent<RectTransform>().transform.localScale = cameraViewPort;
}
```

Comment: is ur game in 2d or 3d? is the gameObject(sofa) u r mentioning part of the world or a UI object?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using UGUI,

```
GameObject g = Instantiate(dimUiPrefab);
RectTransform rectTransform = g.GetComponent<RectTransform>();
// Set size
rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(width, height);
// Set position
rectTransform.position = new Vector3(posX, posY, posZ);
```

Comment: It doesnt answer my question. The UI will be resizable when I change the furniture. It doesnt have a fixed heigh or width

Comment: @donhasan That sounds like a case of "can't have your cake and eat it too." Do you want it to be user-resizable or match-the-object's-size?

Comment: match objects's size. When I change my furniture and run the code, new dimension will be shown in runtime

Comment: It sounds like a mathematical problem. The UI size can be calculated by new furniture from a calibration object  and  viewport changed.